# Get dynamic property value in angular 2 animation

Tags: angular

Hello I m designing an angular 2 app with some animations. What I wanna do is animate an div according to states.

here is the animation decorator

```
trigger('test', [
state('open', style({height: '300px'})),
state('close', style({height: '60px'})),
state('between', style({height: '*'})),
transition('* => between', [style({height: '*'}), // Dont get the height dynamically
animate('5000ms', style({height: '300px'}))]),
transition('closed <=> open', animate('1000ms'))
])
```

What the scenario is initially the state is 'closed' so when i click open button the state changes to 'open' and the div height expands and collaps. Click button has vice versa functionality. this is working properly.

But i do have other functionality where user can drag the div manually and div expands so then i change the state to 'between', so when the user draged the div its height must have changed to 140px(assumption). So I want that 140px height to assigned to 'between' state and animation should start from 140px instead of 60px.

Can someone tell me where M I going wrong. My angular version is 4.